# Can we consider changing "What topics can I ask about here?" to something clearer?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

When you visit a help center on Stack Exchange sites, for example, [that of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help), the first question under *Asking* is [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As other SE sites that I know such as English Language and Usage, Japanese and English Language Learners, etc., they list not only on-topic criteria, but also off-topic criteria.

Can it be changed to something clearer such as

> What is on-topic and off-topic here?
>
> What topics can and can't I ask about here?
>
> What scope does and doesn't this site cover?
>
> , etc.

The reason why I raise this issue is one user thought *off-topicness* is only mentioned on [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as indicated on this [English Language and Usage question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9606/information-about-off-topicness-on-the-on-topic-help-page). I think the clearer, the better.

Comment: That one user from DIY or the user from Cooking?

Comment: Why do two pages even exist for this? They should just be combined into one.

Comment: @hichris123 One is for each site's specific on-topicness and off-topicness and the other is for general SE's policy. If you combined the two into one, it will be too long I am afraid.

Comment: I don't think it would be. Especially considering that people are probably only going to read one or the other; they're not going to look at two different pages to determine whether they should ask their question (who knows if they even read the one!).

Comment: @hichris123 That's exactly my point. Probably I am wasting my time by asking this question here.